# Responsive columns gallery, maintaining independent scroll

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

I want to build this layout with columns, which have an independent scroll.
Sort of a portfolio/gallery.

How can I make it responsive, but still maintain the individual scroll?

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Hard to explain, better with pictures:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ0VG.jpg)

cheers

Comment: maybe can flexbox help you (if you don't know what it's, do this tutorial https://flexboxfroggy.com/ )

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

use `position: sticky` for the headbar